# Maven2 + Eclipse 3.5 web Project Errors

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, jakarta-ee, maven

I'm using Maven 2.2 to build Simple Web Project and Integrate it to Eclipse:

I'm doing it the following way:

1) Going to my workspace directory using command line:

2) Create Project using the following command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.vanilla.test -DartifactId=myTest -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
```

3) Convert this project to Eclipse project:

```
cd myTest
 mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=R7
```

When I import then project to Eclispe I have red 'x' on the project name. Although, I tried to Clean project, to refresh it or run index.jsp, I can't fix it. 
No any other problems with the project.

Why does it happen?

Comment: The 'problems' view in Eclipse must be showing some additonal information abotu the error. Do you see anything there? One possible reason is incorrect JDK version for the project.

Comment: @Vijay, I'm using jdk 1.6.20 is there any way to check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should [configure the workspace](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/configure-workspace-mojo.html) before converting to Eclipse project.

```
mvn eclipse:configure-workspace -Declipse.workspace=<path-of-your-workspace>
```

Comment: This is normal workspace which was used for another peoject and it was configured inside of eclipse.